# Powershell - Write Object to File

Tags: powershell, export, compareobject

when I want a full compare of two textfiles linewise I have the correct result when I use:

```
$test = compare-object -referenceobject $srcobject -differenceobject $compareobject -CaseSensitive
$test = $test | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | select 'InputObject'
```

But afterwards I have serios issues to simply write this stuff to a file.

When i use:

1. Out-File, it makes a cut off and I don't want many spaces in the end of each line
2. Export-CSV, it adds me a `"` to every line at the beginning and the end
3. Set-Content, it adds me `"@{InputObject="` and a `}` every line

How can I export the data without these limitations?

Regards,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$test = compare-object -referenceobject $srcobject -differenceobject $compareobject -CaseSensitive
$test = $test | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | *select -ExpandProperty InputObject*
```